# Change icon on of an App in iOS 4 in run-time

Tags: objective-c, ios

How can I change the icon of my App in iOS 4 at run-time the way the icon  of the Calendar app changes based on the date today?

I want to publish a 4 digit number number once per day without the user having to open the app to chaeck it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best you can do right now within the bounds of Apple-sanctioned APIs is to add a red badge with a number to the icon using the UIApplication `applicationIconBadgeNumber` property.  Not sure if it's big enough to fit 4 digits though.

That's if you want to set it while the app is open.  To update the badge in the background, you will need to either post a `UILocalNotification` (if you know ahead of time when and what the badge should say), or use push notifications.

Comment: As the number grows, the badge elongates to fit it. You may run into a problem if the number goes above the hundreds of thousands, though.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do this using the iOS SDK (you can badge your icon, but you can't modify the icon itself.) If you would like to see this feature added to iOS, file an enhancement request at http://bugreporter.apple.com.