# Changing iPhone app icon through Cocoa Touch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change icon on of an App in iOS 4 in run-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888681/change-icon-on-of-an-app-in-ios-4-in-run-time)

Is there any way to change the app icon through Cocoa Touch, the way that Calendar app does?

Comment: do you mean how to add a number (or ***badge***) to the icon?

Comment: No.  Changing the entire icon, the same way that the Calendar app works (displaying an app icon based on the date).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope! (or not without jailbreaking and releasing your app in cydia that is) All applications that come with the device run with different permissions than the ones that you install from the app store, and the 'app store apps' can only modify files in their sandbox. the icon.png is not in the sandbox, or the "Documents" folder, it is in the "Appname.app" folder.

Comment: @Epic_orange That's a good explanation, but the app can still access files in its bundle (AppName.app). If you include pictures, videos, etc with the app, you can access and display these. The fact that the bundle is signed with a distribution certificate is what prevents its modification, not permissions.

Comment: @Jack so if the iphone is jailbroken, and codesign checks have been disabled, what would happen if the application modified a file in the AppName.app folder like the icon? would it work?

Comment: @Epic_orange Yes, it would work. If the device is jailbroken you can update the icon two different ways: either change the icon picture or update Info.plist. And as you said, when a device is jailbroken, code sign checks are disabled which is why the app bundle can be modified and the app will still be allowed to launch.

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not possible. The icon is set in Info.plist which is part of the app bundle. The app bundle is a collection of all of the files that make up the app (all pictures, videos, files you dragged into Xcode). When submitted to the App Store, the app bundle is signed with a certificate that prevents its modification (so that you cannot change any parts of the app after approval AND so that the device knows it has received a copy from Apple that has not been tampered with along the way). If the icon is set in Info.plist and this cannot be modified, then we're going to have a problem!

This issue is resolved for Newsstand apps. When a magazine is updated, it would only make sense for the icon to update to a picture of the latest issue. If your app is a Newsstand app and you use the NewsstandKit framework, then you can simply change the icon using the code below.

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
[app setNewsstandIconImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:file]];
```

Newsstand apps still have a generic icon and icon properties set in Info.plist, but the system can change the icon when told by the app.

Comment: Can you make any app a news stand app, just to use this functionality?

Comment: @AndrewJohnson No, the app has to offer specific newsstand content to be placed in Newsstand (e.g. your app has to be a newspaper, magazine, etc.). I made an app for my school newspaper and tried to place it in Newsstand; however, they told me I couldn't do this because the app required authentication, so they are pretty strict.